# How to browse the nodes of an OPC UA server with Rust?

Tags: rust, opc

I want to browse a known OPC UA server endpoint to get the nodes in order to poll them later with Rust.

I have been using the [locka99/opcua crate](https://github.com/locka99/opcua) and managed to use their samples to read values of known nodes (of the sample server), but I can not get any browsing to work.

There is a `browse` method on the session struct, but it requires a `BrowseDescription` as argument, which in itself requires already a `NodeId`:

```
session.browse(BrowseDescription {
    // how can I know the parameters?
})
```

How can I build the `BrowseDescription` struct (with a `NodeId`) if the `NodeId` is what I am looking for?

Comment: What's wrong with reading the documentation for [`BrowseDescription`](https://docs.rs/opcua-client/0.5.0/opcua_client/prelude/service_types/struct.BrowseDescription.html)?

Comment: Nothing really. I just don't know how to get the parameters to build a BrowseDescription. Mostly (as mentioned in the question), I don't know where to get the NodeId for the BrowseDescription, as getting the list of NodeIds is my initial problem.

Comment: `NodeId` [implements `Default`](https://docs.rs/opcua-client/0.5.0/opcua_client/prelude/node_id/struct.NodeId.html#impl-Default), doesn't the default value work?

Answer (score 2):

I know it is a very old question, but since I stumbled over this as well, here is what I found in an issue from the linked repo. This helped me to get started:

https://github.com/locka99/opcua/issues/105#issuecomment-813046915

```
let results = session.browse(&[BrowseDescription {
  node_id: ObjectId::RootFolder.into(),
  browse_direction: BrowseDirection::Forward,
  reference_type_id:  ReferenceTypeId::Organizes,
  include_subtypes: true,
  node_class_mask: 0,
  result_mask: BrowseDescriptionResultMask::all().bits() as u32,
}]);
```